# Issue in Bootstrap Modal with ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a issue when I try to show a modal with a image click in asp.net+ bootstrap

This is my modal code, I copy this from a [web site](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my trigger object:

```
<img onclick="ShowModal();" data-target="#basicModal" src="Images/productface/<%:prd.pr_facepicpath%>.png" />
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#basicModal').modal();
    });
    function ShowModal() {
            $('#basicModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

this is my js libs declaration:

```
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modal.js"></script>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: You posted your code, but you didn't say what's not working about it. What's the issue?

Comment: is tru... this is the issue:  TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like you have not include bootstrap `modal.js` file.

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Only comes when you have not included modal library.

You can get required js file from https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

Comment: <code><script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/modal.js"></script></code>

Comment: they are my js libs declared. I add modal.js and still happend :S :(

Comment: I delete this line $('#basicModal').modal('show'); and now is working well, but your awnser helpme so much, I need to add modal.js too